# AWS cloud formation : Inbound rules not getting added with this cloud formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am learning to create stacks using cloud formation template, I am trying to create an EC2 instance using cloud formation template with security groups so I can ssh to it as well.
My cloud formation template is :

```
{
    "Description": "Create an EC2 instance by AWS CloudFormation",
    "Resources": {
        "EC2instance": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {
                "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1b",
                "ImageId": "ami-08e697937cb1d2fa0",
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "SubnetId": "subnet-f27e50aa",
                 "KeyName": "DeepNewKP"
            }
        },
        "SecurityGroupDemoSvrTraffic": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupName": "sgDemoSvr",
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": 22,
                        "ToPort": 22,
                        "CidrIp": "115.110.123.22/32",
                        "Description": "For traffic from Internet"
                    }
                ],
                "GroupDescription": "Security Group for demo server",
                "VpcId": "vpc-ba7ef3dd"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stack is getting created but when I check the security groups I don't find the rule that I mentioned there. Because of this, I can't ssh to it(I am able to ssh it after adding that manually). I want to know what I am doing wrong in the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only issue i see is your not attaching the security group to the instance, so add the below to the `EC2instance` properties:

`"SecurityGroupIds": [{"Ref":"SecurityGroupDemoSvrTraffic"}]`

See [SecurityGroupIds section of the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html)